# Hpricot / nokogiri - Parse SVG / XML file to get colors used

Tags: ruby, svg, xml-parsing, nokogiri, hpricot

I need help in finding all colors used in an SVG (XML) file.

For example, i need the list of colors used in the image http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e9/Pepsi_logo_2008.svg

I was trying with hpricot / nokogiri gems to do something like,

-->  doc.search("['fill:']") .. etc

But i am unable to get the proper result.

If there is any **command line tool for linux** like inkscape to get the colors it will be helpful.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533947/counting-colors-in-an-svg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e9/Pepsi_logo_2008.svg'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML open(url)
puts doc.xpath('//*[contains(@style,"fill")]').map{|e| e[:style][/fill:([^;]*)/, 1]}.uniq
```

Comment: This did what i need... Thanks Guardiario.. :)

But there are few SVG's which has colors which doesn't comes under style tag (@style,"fill")... 
Is it possible to handled them dynamically..?

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to vote it up and mark it correct.